# Как написать код с обработкой и заменой символов С++

Tags: c++, массивы, символы

[[image: исходное задание]

На вход поступают строки состоящие из слов из символоов, работаем посиивольно, нужно определить является ли комбинация символов словом при этом в строках встречаются цифрв пробелы двоеточия и тп.

Задача: Все последующие вхождения одинак слов нужно заменить на комбинацию s(n) где n номер первого вхождения слова

При этом все состоит из строчных структур которые входят в массив

( работать по такому принципу: создать пустой массив и последовательным сравнением символов, определяя слова начал его заполнять, проблема в том что при посиивольном сравнении, когда слово состоит например из 3 букв а заменить нужно на s(4), то в новый массив вводится только s(4 иначе теряется следующий символ
Приветствуются и другие идеи решения, если удастся создать рабочий код[image: 1 часть кода][image: 2 часть кода]

[image: 3 часть кода][image: 4 часть][image: 5 часть кода][image: 6 часть кода][image: 7 часть кода][image: 8 часть кода м обработкой в ней проблема]

[image: 9 часть кода с обработкой в ней проблема]
[image: 10 часть кода][image: 11 часть][image: 12 часть][image: конец кодп]

Comment: Вы всерьез думаете, что кто-то будет разбираться с полуслепенькими фото и даже перенабирать приведенный на них код?

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)